# How to show that there is a bijection from Weyl group to $\{B \subset G: T \subset B, \text{$B$ is a Borel subgroup of $G$}\}$?

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group, $T$ a maximal torus of $G$, $W=N_G(T)$ the Weyl group of $G$. How to show that there is a bijection from $W$ to $\{B \subset G: T \subset B, \text{$B$ is a Borel subgroup of $G$}\}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Translated into the langage of Lie algebras, it amounts to shows that any Borel subalgebra which contains a fixed Cartan $\mathfrak h$ is on the form $\mathfrak b = \mathfrak h \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in \Delta^+} \mathfrak g_{\alpha}$ where $\Delta^+$ is a set of positive roots.

Comment: This should essentially boil down to the statement that the Weyl group acts simply transitively on the bases of the root system, once you translate everything correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Weyl group $W$ you want $N_G(T)/Z_G(T)$, not $N_G(T)$. Actually $Z_G(T) = T$, so $W = N_G(T)/T$, but this is a difficult theorem.

Fix a Borel subgroup $B$ of $G$ containing $T$.  The claim is that

$$nZ_G(T) \mapsto nBn^{-1} \tag{$n \in N_G(T)$}$$

is a bijection from $W$ onto the set of Borel subgroups of $G$ containing $T$.

**Well defined/injective:** If $n \in N_G(T)$, then $nBn^{-1}$ is obviously still a Borel subgroup of $G$ containing $T$.  For $n_1, n_2 \in N_G(T)$, we have

$$n_1Bn_1^{-1} = n_2Bn_2^{-1} \iff n_1^{-1}n_2 \in N_G(B) \iff n_1^{-1}n_2 \in B$$

because $N_G(B) = B$ (Springer, *Linear Algebraic Groups*, 6.49).  We also have $$N_G(T) \cap B = N_B(T) = Z_B(T) = Z_G(T) \cap B$$ where the middle equality is 6.36 (ii).  Since is always in $n_1^{-1}n_2 \in N_G(T)$, we have $n_1^{-1}n_2 \in B \iff n_1^{-1}n_2 \in Z_G(T) \iff n_1Z_G(T) = n_2Z_G(T)$.

**Surjective**: Let $B'$ be a Borel subgroup of $G$ containing $T$.  All Borel subgroups of $G$ are conjugate (6.27 (ii)), so there exists a $g \in G$ such that $gBg^{-1} = B'$.  Then $gTg^{-1}$ is a maximal torus of $B'$.  All maximal tori of $B'$ are conjugate (6.35 (iii)), so there exists a $b' \in B'$ such that $b'gTg^{-1}b'^{-1} = T$.  Then $n = b'g \in N_G(T)$, with

$$nBn^{-1} = B'$$

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that the group $W$ is in bijection with the set of all base of $\Phi$ where $\Phi$ is the root system associated to $\mathfrak h := \text{Lie}(T)$. In fact it is probably the hardest statement since you took a different definition of the Weyl group, first you should show that $W$ coincide with the reflection group of the root system.

Once you know it, you notice that if $\Delta$ is a base, that is a set of simple roots, then $\mathfrak b(\Delta) := \mathfrak h \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in \Phi^+} \mathfrak g_{\alpha}$ is a Borel subalgebra, that is a maximal solvable algebra. It is surely solvable because its commutator is nilpotent, and by construction it's maximal.

For prove that any Borel $\mathfrak b \supset \mathfrak h$ is on this form, let $\mathfrak b = \mathfrak h \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha} \mathfrak g_{\alpha}$ the weight decomposition. Again, as before the $\alpha$ should be a subset of $\Delta^+$ for some base $\Delta$. But we are done because it means $\mathfrak b \subset \mathfrak b(\Delta)$ and by maximality they are equal.